# What is the best way to ensure a regex in OCaml matches the entire input string?

Tags: regex, ocaml

In OCaml, I'm trying to check if a regex matches the **entire** input string, not just a prefix or a suffix or the potion of the input string before the first newline.

For example, I want to avoid a regex of `[0-9]+` matching against strings like these:

```
let negative_matches = [
    "  123"; (* leading whitespace *)
    "123  "; (* trailing whitespace *)
    "123\n"; (* trailing newline *)
]
```

I see that [`Str.string_match`](https://ocaml.org/api/Str.html) still returns `true` when trailing characters do not match the pattern:

```
# List.map (fun s -> Str.string_match (Str.regexp "[0-9]+") s 0) negative_matches;;
- : bool list = [false; true; true]
```

Adding `$` to the pattern helps in the second example, but `$` is documented to only "match at the end of the line", so the third example still matches

```
# List.map (fun s -> Str.string_match (Str.reg  exp "[0-9]+$") s 0) negative_matches;;
- : bool list = [false; false; true]
```

I don't see a true "end of string" matcher (like `\z` in Java and Ruby) documented, so the best answer I've found is to additionally check the length of the input string against the length of the match using [`Str.match_end`](https://ocaml.org/api/Str.html):

```
# List.map (fun s -> Str.string_match (Str.reg  exp "[0-9]+") s 0 && Str.match_end () = String.length s) negative_matches;;
- : bool list = [false; false; false]
```

Please tell me I'm missing something obvious and there is an easier way.

Edit: note that I'm not always looking to match against a simple regex like `[0-9]+`. I'd like a way to match an arbitrary regex against the entire input string.

Comment: Anchor the regexp with `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end.

Comment: I don't know ocaml but standard is to use `^` at start of regex and `$` at the end, like this: `^search$`.

Comment: Will not work if the requirement is to only contain `0-9` digits, _but_ if you just need to check if the string contains a valid _int_, you can try using `int_of_string` on it. If it fails you'll get `Exception: Failure "int_of_string"` which can be handled.

Comment: @Barmar: As mentioned in the question, I already tried these anchors and "$" matches the end of the first line in the string, not the end of the string.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `\A` and `\Z` rather than `^` and `$`.

Comment: In addition to the suggestions to anchor the beginning and end of line/string, are you sure you don't want to allow whitespace at the beginning/end of the string given how easy it would be to trim those off?  `\A\s*\d+\s*\Z`?

Comment: @Chris Sadly, it doesn't appear like OCaml supports `\A` and `\Z`. And this isn't just about whitespace. Subsequent lines can contain anything and still pass the regex: `Str.string_match (Str.regexp "^[0-9]+$") "1234\nsecond_line_of_text" 0;;
- : bool = true`

Comment: OCaml regex is a bit limited when you're used to langs with PCRE regexes, try https://mmottl.github.io/pcre-ocaml/ library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing something obvious. There is an easier way. If

```
[^0-9]
```

is matched in the input string you will know it contains a non-digit character.

---

Unfortunately, I don't think `Str` offers a better way to ensure the whole string has been matched than your own solution, or the similar, slightly clearer alternative:

```ml
Str.string_match (Str.regexp "[0-9]+") s 0 && Str.matched_string s = s
```

Or you could just check for the presence of a newline character as that is the fly in the ointment as you show.

And, of course, there are other regular expression libraries available that do not have this problem.

Comment: In this particular example, sure. But I'm looking for a general way to match an arbitrary regex against an entire string. Constructing an inverse regex isn't always practical or easy to understand.

Comment: @AlexBlanck Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

try this for your example

```
(?<![^A-z]|\w)[0-9]+(?![^A-z]|\w)
```

[test it here](https://regexr.com/6j2e4)
if you want to generate other patterns you can start by knowing this

(?<!'any group you don't want it to appear ***before*** your desire')

(?!'any group you don't want it to appear ***after*** your desire')

Comment: Interesting idea, but I don't think that ocaml's `Str` doesn't support lookbehind and lookahead nor `\w`